# Add #states in a webform

Tags: 7

I have a webform in my site in that am trying to make toggle for a radio button but the field i require do not have #states .How to add the attribute #states in a webform component using form alter?

Answer (score 0):

Try [Webform conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module, it provides you the same thing.

Comment: new version of webform has this feature inbuilt. :)

Comment: Great........ :)

Answer (score 0):

The [Webform Conditional](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_conditional) module may be of use here. However, the Webform Conditional module is now included in [Webform](https://drupal.org/project/webform):

> As of Webform version 7.x-4.0-alpha2 this module has been merged into
>   Webform and is no longer necessary.

It appears the latest version of the Webform module does support `#states`. Here are a few related links with more information about `#states` and Webforms:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/1748218
- http://www.shawnduncan.org/2013/states-property-webforms-node-edit-fieldsets

Comment: am using webform version 7.x-3.20 .Is it Compatible to that?

Comment: Unfortunately no. You'll need to to upgrade to 4.x following these instructions: https://www.drupal.org/node/1609324